# A method that doesn't lock is blocked on object monitor

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, monitor

While investigating non-responsiveness in a large Java Swing application, I discovered (using jstack) that one thread was in this state:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
```

However, the method it is blocked in (i.e at the top of the stack trace) isn't synchronized and doesn't do any locking. Its code is just (with names changed):

```
public Thing makeThing(String foo) {
    return new Thing(foo);
}
```

The `Thing` constructor just does the following. It extends a class, and the base constructor only assigns fields as well. There is also one class constructed by an inline initializer. None of these are synchronized.

```
public Thing(String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

So I can't understand why it's blocked. Someone suggested this could be related to GC "stop the world" - but I thought a stop-the-world would not be visible to JStack. Also, `Thing` is not a Swing object.

Stack trace:

```
factory.makeThing
factory.makeThing
dao.retrieveThing
ThingArray.get
...
ThingCache.getThing
    - locked (a java.lang.Object)
...
Thread.run
```

Comment: For the record: you have a method called Thing? That is not a constructor? That code snippet looks rather weird. If the code is really correct, you should learn how to properly name methods in Java. Names should be meaningful. And method names contain a verb and start lowercase.

Comment: If that is a constructor call and you forgot the new keyword... I would lean towards gc issues. And then have someone analyze gc log files next.

Comment: @GhostCat - Missing "new" added. Production code uses proper naming.

Comment: "`Thread`" and "Swing" is a big red flag - you know that Swing is single threaded? That you cannot access or mutate Swing objects from any thread other than the EDT? Doing so results in exactly the sort of behaviour you are experiencing.

Comment: @Boris - yes I'm aware of that. In the example, Thing is not a Swing class.

Comment: You need to show the code that gets executed by the `Thing` constructor (and the code it calls, etc.). Almost certainly that code is (directly or indirectly) taking a monitor lock.

Comment: @DanielPryden - If that was relevant, I'd expect to see the Thing constructor in at the top of the stack trace (i.e. the method it is blocked in). In any case, all the constructor does is assign the parameter to a field. No locking.

Comment: What does `Thing` extend? Does it do something in it's field initialializers or non-static initializer blocks? +++ Give us the stacktrace (feel free to rename things, but do it consistently).

Comment: @maaartinus - Thanks for the suggestions. `Thing` does extend another domain object; just one field assign in constructor. And one inline initializer; constructor for that class also has no locking. I've included parts of stack trace, I've tried to change the names to something meaningful. Would be a bit tricky to rewrite it all. Bizarrely, the makeThing method appears twice even though it doesn't call itself.

Comment: I see ``ThingArray`` in the stack trace, probably the lock is acquired by some thread safe collection holding ``Thing`` objects?

Comment: @NikitaGorbachevski - Thanks for commenting. There is a method further down the stack trace that holds a lock (not `ThingArray`, but `ThingCache`) However, I don't see that causing this symptom. That method gets the lock successfully, then calls some other methods while holding it. This doesn't explain why `makeThing` is blocking.

Comment: Probably the cache is shared by multiple threads and while one of them holds the lock other are blocked. Blocking doesn't mean that something bad is happening, it just says that some thread is waiting for a different thread to release its lock in order to get the monitor lock.

Comment: @NikitaGorbachevski - Blocking sometimes implies something bad like a deadlock. The app is showing signs of non-responsiveness. To determine whether this is particular block is a problem or not, it would be really helpful to know why this thread is blocking, because at the minute it appears to be blocking for no reason at all.

Comment: Are you using any AOP or bytecode rewriting features? It's possible that the `makeThing` that's actually executing (and blocking) isn't the `makeThing` that you have source code for.

Comment: @DanielPryden - That's a very good point. App is using ZKM obfuscator. Will crack out decompiler to see what it's actually doing. Thanks for the tip.